# Limiting the number of loaded items in memory with paging library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging, android-paging-library

I'm using `paging library` to load and display the data from server:

```
dataFactory = DataSourceFactory()
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
    .setPageSize(25)
    .setInitialLoadSizeHint(25 * 2)
    .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
    .build()
dataList = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, CreditTransaction>(dataFactory, config).build()
adapter.submitList(dataList.value)
```

I'm also using the `PageKeyedDataSource` for `DataSourceFactory`

And when I scroll the list for a long time I have lots of items in memory. I also know that since `Paging 2.1.0-alpha01` we have `page dropping`, `PagedList.Config.Builder.setMaxSize()` for limiting the number of loaded items in memory. But this feature doesn't work with `PageKeyedDataSource`. 
Are there other solutions for limiting the number of loaded items in memory which can work with `PageKeyedDataSource`?